# Mapping a position to an array index

Tags: c++, arrays

Backstory:
I'm making a simple maze game, where the maze is procedurally generated. I represent the maze as a 2D array of rooms, with 4 booleans storing whether or not each corner of a room has a wall. (if Room.south_wall == false, than the room is connected to the room to its south.) Each room and can have an arbitrary length and width. For simplicity's sake, I set it so that the length and width is determined at the beginning of generation and applied to all rooms. The position of the player is stored using 2 floats, one is their x coordinates, one is their y coordinates. The maze looks something like this (Thick black lines are the visible walls, thin red lines represent the 2d array):

[image]

As you can see, each room has a length and width of 3. What I want to be able to do is determine what room the player is in, given their position. So for example, in this instance:

[image]

The player is in room (1,0) (I've marked the origin and the center of room (1,0) to help see this)

I know this should be a simple question, but I've been unable to come up with anything for a few days now. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if this isn't enough information.

Comment: Your player position is wrong, it should be in room (1,1) based off of it's coordinates.

Comment: As is room (1,0)'s position, you've mixed the alignment of your rooms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the player position `px`,`py` and your rooms are aligned so that room(0,0) is centred at (0.0, 0.0) then the index of the room would be

```
#include<cmath>
ix = int(std::round(px / room_width));
iy = int(std::round(py / room_height));
```

Also, as a general rule it's best to make `room_width` and `room_height` a constant rather than use a 'bare' (aka magic) number just in case you want to change it later.

Comment: Doesn't work all the time. Imagine my room had a width of 4. As you can see, the origin of each room is in the exact center, so therefore the distance from the origin to a wall is 2. Lets say position = (3,0). ix = int(px / room_width) = int(3 / 4) = 0, when my position is actually in room (1,0)

Comment: @redsoxfantom Sorry, I didn't realise that you hadn't aligned your rooms with the origin and were pushing into the negatives. I've modified the above to work in your particular case.